# Why does Spring have class JdbcDaoSupport, but no analagous class JmsSupport?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-jms

Why does the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/about) have class [`JdbcDaoSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html) that requires a [`DataSource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html?is-external=true) and creates a [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) internally, but has no analagous class `JmsSupport` that might require a [JMS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_Message_Service) [`ConnectionFactory`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html?is-external=true) and create a [`JmsTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html)?

As I understand, the purpose of class `JdbcDaoSupport` is to eliminate redundant instances of `JdbcTemplate` (one per `DataSource` instance) in an application context.  Instead, the container creates instances of an application DAO, each of which derives from `JdbcDaoSupport`, accepts a unique `DataSource` and provides this `DataSource` to the `JdbcDaoSupport` parent instance which in turn provides it to its internal `JmsTemplate`.

Why doesn't Spring provide an analogous class `JmsSupport` that would serve to reduce the number of `JmsTemplate` instances in an application context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JdbcDaoSupport` is little more than a user of a `JdbcTemplate` that also extends `DaoSupport`. It provides a base implementation of the DAO design pattern for JDBC, like other classes do for Hibernate, JPA, and others.

A lot of people don't use the DAO paradigm; instead, they define a singleton `JdbcTemplate` that they inject directly into their service layer.

For JMS, there is - as far as I know - no generic design pattern like the DAO, and there's no other possible variations on "a user of `JmsTemplate`". You should use a singleton `JmsTemplate`: there's nothing more to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Spring in Action, my main source of information about Spring, does not mention the points that you make.